# Convert list of strings of tuples to list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

The problem: I have to convert a list of strings of tuples into a normal list of tuples. The reason is that I want to plot the (x,y) coordinates over an image.

I tried `map`,`join`, unzipping it, `int()`, `float()` but nothing seems to work. If I try the most logical way, using `int()` I get the following error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '(50,144)'

This is my list of strings of tuples

```py
vertices = ['(50,144)', '(242,144)', '(242,367)', '(50,367)']
type(vertices) >> list
type(vertices[0]) >> str
```

Comment: where are those strings coming from?

Comment: from a response using the google vision API

Comment: I haven't worked with that API, was just thinking there might be a more fancier way to obtain this data than manually parsing it into tuples. But yeah, haven't tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) to safely parse the strings of tuples:

```
from ast import literal_eval

list(map(literal_eval, vertices))
# [(50, 144), (242, 144), (242, 367), (50, 367)]
```

Answer (score 1):

A safe way would be parsing the strings yourself:

```
verts = [tuple(map(int, s[1:-1].split(','))) for s in vertices]

print(verts)
print(type(verts))
print(type(verts[0]))
print(type(verts[0][0]))
```

Output:

```
[(50, 144), (242, 144), (242, 367), (50, 367)]
<class 'list'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'int'>
```

You can also use `eval` but only if you are confident of the input's format (list of strings representing tuples of integers):

```
vertices = ['(50,144)', '(242,144)', '(242,367)', '(50,367)']

verts = [eval(s) for s in vertices]

print(type(verts))
print(type(verts[0]))
print(type(verts[0][0]))
```

Output:

```
[(50, 144), (242, 144), (242, 367), (50, 367)]
<class 'list'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'int'>
```